# fire animation onclick instead of hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

how will i add the flip animation to a button. The + button on the frontside instead of flipping on hover could be a start.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/92xNm

i understand that the animation comes from the

```
.image-flip:hover .backside,
.image-flip.hover .backside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.image-flip:hover .frontside,
.image-flip.hover .frontside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

but how could i add this to a click event instead?

im using C# blazor if it changes anything.

Comment: The standard way would be to add a class with JS (If you're okay with JS solutions then adding the JS tag might be worthwhile) The CSS already has a `hover` class you could add to the element.

Comment: Prefer not to use the JS way, but i can probally transform it into my blazor solution. so will try and add the #Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `:active`?
I think the better way is to use JS onclick and add/remove class to it.